# WebGL half float equivelant?

Tags: glsl, webgl, floating-point

I'm trying to find a `half float` for the purposes of doing math in a fragment shader, not trying to have a half float texture.

Is there an equivalent of the `half float` data type in WebGL?
I know you can create a `lowp` float, but is that the same, or not necessarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lowp` is the same as a `half float`. But why does it matter that much? Are you really needing this kind of optimization right now? I'd say just use plain `float` and think about this only when you check that this is a bottleneck for either performance or memory or bandwidth.

Comment: I'm storing data in textures, but when I pull it out via bilinear sampling, it comes out blocky (quantized). I wanted to see how it looked when I did the bilinear interpolation myself with low precision to see if id get the same results to know if that was what was going on or not.

Comment: Makes sense! Good luck :)